Is the positivity of $\lambda$ in PDE Separation of Variables changing the characteristics of the corresponding ODE solution?
I am working on the following PDE question:
$ u_{rr} + \frac{1}{r}u_{r} + \frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta} = 0,\\
 0 < r_1 < r_2 < \infty,\\
 0 \leq \theta_1 < \theta_2 \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$
The first part of the question is to derive the pair of ODEs using SoV, and then from this, solve the the ODE for $R(r)$ given either $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda > 0$. The question advises me that the result when $\lambda > 0$ should return oscillatory solutions.
This is my working so far:
We can express this PDE, $u(r,\theta)$ as a multiplication between two single-variable functions. That is,
\begin{align*}
    u(r,\theta) = R(r)\Theta(\theta).
\end{align*}
Differentiating with respect to the required variables specified in our PDE, we can rewrite our function as:
\begin{align*}
    R''(r)\Theta(\theta) + \frac{1}{r}R'(r)\Theta(\theta) + \frac{1}{r^2}R(r)\Theta''(\theta) &= 0 \hspace{0.3cm} \text{and dividing through by $R(r)\Theta(\theta)$,}\\
    \frac{R''(r)}{R(r)} + \frac{R'(r)}{rR(r)} + \frac{\Theta''(\theta)}{r^2\Theta(\theta)} &= 0\\
    \frac{R''(r)}{R(r)} + \frac{R'(r)}{rR(r)} &= - \frac{\Theta''(\theta)}{r^2\Theta(\theta)}\\
\frac{r^2R''(r)}{R(r)} + \frac{rR'(r)}{R(r)} &= - \frac{\Theta''}{\Theta}\\
\end{align*}
This is the critical point here where my question lies. Sometimes in my textbook, $- \lambda$ is chosen instead since "it is convenient to exhibit the minus sign explicitly". I have tried following this question using both $\lambda$ and $- \lambda$ and the resutling solution for the ODE seems completely different, which confuses me since $\lambda$ should be arbitrary. I might be looking at this from the wrong lense but so far none of my classmates have found an explanation either.
If I were to choose $\lambda$, we have:
\begin{align*}
r^2R''(r) + rR'(r) - \lambda R(r) &= 0, \hspace{0.3cm} \text{now assume R(r) is of the form $r^k$ for some $k$},\\
    r^kk(k-1)r^{k-2} + rkr^{k-1} - \lambda r^k &= 0\\
    r^k(k(k-1) + k - \lambda) &= 0\\
    k^2 - \lambda &= 0\\
    \therefore k &= \pm \sqrt{\lambda}, \hspace{0.3cm} \text{and so our resulting solution to the ODE is of the form}\\
    R(r) &= C_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda}r} + C_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}r}, \hspace{0.3cm} \text{where $C_1$, $C_2$ are constants.}
\end{align*}
Now if I arbitrary chose $-\lambda$ instead, I have computed:
\begin{align*}
    k(k-1)r^{k-2} + \frac{1}{r} \left( kr^{k-1} \right) + \frac{\lambda}{r^2} \left( r^k \right) &= 0\\
    k(k-1)r^{k-2} + kr^{k-2} + \lambda r^{k-2} &= 0\\
    r^{k-2} \left( k(k-1) + k + \lambda \right) &= 0\\
    k(k-1) + k + \lambda &= 0\\
    k^2 - k + k + \lambda &= 0\\
    k^2 &= -\lambda\\
    \therefore \hspace{0.2cm} k &= \pm i \sqrt{\lambda}\\
\end{align*}
With this result, we can express the function $R(r)$ as
\begin{align*}
    R(r) = C_1e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}r} + C_2e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}r}
\end{align*}
Utilising Euler's Theorem we can rewrite this more simply as
\begin{align*}
    R(r) &= C_1\left( \cos(\lambda\log(r)) + i\sin(\lambda\log(r)) \right) + C_2 \left( \cos(-\lambda\log(r)) + i\sin(-\lambda\log(r)) \right)\\
\end{align*}
From here we can simplify down since we know cosine functions to be even and sine functions to be odd, so our result becomes
\begin{align*}
    R(r) = A\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\log(r)) + B\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\log(r)), \hspace{0.3cm} \text{where $A,B$ are constants.}
\end{align*}
Is there a reason why I should choose $\lambda$ over $-\lambda$ or vice versa? If someone could please explain the intuition behind this, I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you in advance!

If you had boundary conditions for this problem, you will typically find that one choice of the sign of $\lambda$ will result in infinitely many solutions and the other with none or finitely many

The boundary conditions for the question only come up later in the question, so I don't think they want us thinking about it in terms of them, but that's an interesting notion still

You have several rather serious errors in your formulas. $e^{\pm \sqrt{\lambda}}$ should be $e^{\pm \sqrt{\lambda} , r}$ , and $r^{\pm i \sqrt{\lambda}}$ should be $e^{\pm i \sqrt{\lambda} , r}$.

You were told this sign for $\lambda$ because the other will result in no solutions for the boundary conditions in the problem

The question stated $\lambda$ would produce oscillatory results, but I found $-\lambda$ resulted in this instead, so I'm not sure what to make of that

The question can be answered on a flat rectangle without the complications by metric coefficients.
If you consider a positive elliptic operator applied to a separating product
$$a<x<b, c<y<d:  -f_{x,x} - f_{y,y}=0,  f[x,y]= X(x) \ Y(y)$$
$$\frac{X_i''(x)}{X_i(x)} = \lambda_i^2, \quad \frac{Y_i''(y)}{Y_i(y)} = -\lambda_i^2$$
yos see immediately the for a product solution to be harmonic locally, a trigonometric solution always has to be pared with a hyperbolic solution. So you get potentially two different series expansions, imaginary exponential periodically in one direction and real exponentials in the other direction. The series have to fit the boundary values at the four sides this four fitting processes on the sides are singling out which $\lambda_i$-series, real or imaginary, have to be kept
